# jQuery submit form IF

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hey guys,
I have this great scripts someone on stack overflow helped me out with, except the one major function I need is missing.

This is a game where the user picks a number (by entering that number in a text field) then hits a play button. After they hit the play button a series of numbers will appear, they then have to click on the number that matches their number.

The query script I'm using counts how many times they hit the number and how many times they missed the number. Take a look at the script in action here. [link text](http://jsfiddle.net/DHPQT/)

now what I need it to do, is send the score (hits and misses ) to a database after 3 misses, so I can keep high score. Any ideas? Here's the script.

```
var hitCount = 0,
missCount = 0;

function IsNumeric(n) {
return !isNaN(n);
}

$("#getit").click(function() {
var li = [],
    intervals = 0,
    n = parseInt($('#MyNumber').val());

if (IsNumeric(n)) {
    setInterval(function() {
        li[intervals++ % li.length].text(Math.random() > .1 ? Math.floor(Math.random()        * (10 + n) + (n / 2)) : n).attr('class', '');
    }, <?php echo $time ?>);
}

$('#randomnumber').empty();

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    li.push($('<li />').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if (!$this.hasClass('clicked')) {
            if (parseInt($this.text(), 10) === n) {
                $this.addClass('correct');
                $('#hitcount').text(++hitCount);
            } else {
                $this.addClass('wrong');
                $('#misscount').text(++missCount);
            }
        }

        $this.addClass('clicked');
    }).appendTo('#randomnumber'));
}

return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your fiddle with the solution. Check http://jsfiddle.net/DHPQT/2/.

I marked all the new stuff with a comment in the form of

```
//new ....
```

The main thing to do is checking after

```
$('#misscount').text(++missCount);
```

if `missCount` is 3 and if yes stop the game  and send something

Comment: Thanks this worked great. One thing how would I reset the hit and miss count please after the 3 miss counts are reached so they can play again without refreshing the page. Right now it picks up from the last count.

Comment: this really works great bro. I'm working on ways to make this server side now so the score isn't manipulated.

Answer (score 2):

I've updated your problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DHPQT/4/).

After updating the status Check for the missCount if it is greater than or equal to 3 then stop the play(clear the interval and unbind the event), then save the value using an ajax request.

I've changed the event handling to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of direct click event on the `<li>` elements. Event delegation is better in cases where there are lot of elements to which we have to bind a particular event.

Comment: I like this, like you said the <li> elements freezing once 3 or more hits are reach work much better. Now can the game reset once the play button is clicked again? this way the user doesn't have to refresh the page to play again. Right now, it picks up from the last scores recored when the play button is clicked again.